# Gnome Shell high CPU usage after hibernation

Tags: gnome

I have made hibernation working on my Ubuntu install by following this article: https://medium.com/@lzcoder/enable-hibernate-on-ubuntu-using-uswsusp-s2disk-ae0b71862eb5

What I have noticed is that after I turn on my PC from hibernation, Gnome Shell is taking a lot of CPU power. I have to restart my PC to go back to normal (there are no other cases with such a problem).

What can I do? I haven't found anything useful online. It was mostly GPU driver problem (I have just Intel GPU, so I don't think that is my case).

Output of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 52
drwxrwxr-x 13 username username 4096 Jun 22 16:49  ./
drwx------  3 username username 4096 Jun 23 18:23  ../
drwxrwxr-x  8 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:33 'cpupower@mko-sl.de'/
drwxrwxr-x  5 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:22 'dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com'/
drwxrwxr-x  8 username username 4096 Jun 22 16:49 'gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io'/
drwxrwxr-x  3 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:35 'impatience@gfxmonk.net'/
drwxrwxr-x  2 username username 4096 Jun 19 14:33 'NotificationCounter@coolllsk'/
drwxrwxr-x  2 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:35 'remove-alt-tab-delay@tetrafox.pw'/
drwxrwxr-x  7 username username 4096 Jun 19 07:59 'sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net'/
drwxrwxr-x  4 username username 4096 Jun 19 13:29 'syncthingicon@jay.strict@posteo.de'/
drwxrwxr-x  5 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:27 'TwitchLive_Panel@extensions.maweki.de'/
drwxrwxr-x  5 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:25 'unite@hardpixel.eu'/
drwxrwxr-x  4 username username 4096 Jun 15 17:19 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com'/
```

Output of `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:35  ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 15 17:19  ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 16 20:43 'desktop-icons@csoriano'/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 09:35 'ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com'/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 19 13:20 'ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com'/
```

Output of `free -h`

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4.4Gi       5.7Gi       1.2Gi       5.4Gi       9.6Gi
Swap:          31Gi       307Mi        30Gi
```

Output of `sysctl vm.swappiness` => `vm.swappiness = 60`

[top screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc3uN.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and a screenshot of `top`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, and then restart gnome-shell with ALT+F2, then r, then ENTER. Then view `top` and check gnome-shell, and it should be using <3% of CPU. Later, enable ONE extension at a time and recheck `top`.

Comment: Did not help unfortunately. After I restart my machine, it's all back to normal, so I'm not sure whether a extension can cause this.

Comment: You didn't need to restart your machine, just reload gnome-shell. And "it's all back to normal" is **exactly what we WANT to see when extensions are disabled**. gnome-shell < 3% of CPU. Then you re-enable ONE extension at a time until you find the one that's causing the high CPU%... and the change may not be immediate.

Comment: I did exactly as you said. I disabled all of my extensions, reloaded gnome-shell. I even waited for a while, but gnome-shell is still kicking in. I just wanted to note the thing about the restart. I haven't restarted the machine.

Comment: You had said "After I restart my machine", but I guess you meant reloaded gnome-shell, yes? With extensions disabled, and no mouse movement, what CPU% is gnome-shell showing? Show me another `top` screenshot.

Comment: Sorry. I should have said that differently. The restart was out of context of your instructions. As I said, your instructions were followed without any restart, here is the screenshot after disabling all of my extensions and reloading the gnome-shell https://imgur.com/a/sMHZExE (no change, gnome-shell is still high)

Comment: What I see if two copies of gnome-shell running, and xwayland taking a lot of CPU also. Are you using Wayland? At the login screen, select your user name, then click the cogwheel icon and instead of selecting "Ubuntu with Wayland", select "Ubuntu", then enter your password, and see if `top` looks better, and check for two copies of gnome-shell, and the high CPU usage for gnome-shell. Report back.

Comment: I had a very similar issue after resuming from hibernation, my `top` output look similar to yours, however that output is misleading, if you check out the full process details using `ps -ef | grep gnome-shell` or `ps -ef | grep <pid>` you'll notice that that is not the `gnome-shell` binary (`/usr/bin/gnome-shell`) but another binary, probably a `gjs` process spawned by Gnome. In my case it was a script that had something to do with notifications. I was able to kill that process (`sudo kill <pid>`) without crashing Gnome. I'm not 100% sure but it also seems like Gnome restarted that script.

Comment: I'll simply repeat this step after every hibernation, I may try to schedule it after resuming.

Comment: @heynnema It was already on Ubuntu (I did not change that ever, I guess it comes as default). I tried Ubuntu on wayland just out of curiosity, no change.

Comment: @Anthony I tried killing everything mentioned `gjs` coming from command you provided. No change. It was still kicking.

Comment: Killing all `gjs` processes is a bit overkill, and could even crash Gnome. The important thing for now is to determine the exact binary that is using up CPU time.

When you run the `top` command, the leftmost column is `PID`, take note of the PID of the process that is using up 99+% of your CPU, and do a `ps -ef | grep 1234` replacing `1234` with the PID you noted in the last step. The output will show you what command was used to launch that process. It is important to know which executable it is that is slowing down your system, in my case `top` showed `gnome-sh...` which was misleading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wayland**

Try this...

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.

**Swap/hibernation**

Your swap partition, or /swapfile, is excessive.

Edit your question with the outputs of these commands, use copy/paste, not a screenshot.

`cat /etc/fstab`

`sudo blkid`

`cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

`grep -i "GRUB_" /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Looks like uncommenting the line with `WaylandEnable=false` helped. After I go back from hibernation, CPU usage is normal. Thanks.